# How to make a pinging system to IP without freeze VB?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, ping

I am trying to make a pinging system to ping an IP in my VB windows form. The current pinging system that I use tends to freeze the application when I enter the text in the textbox. I'm sure there is better ways to do this.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Timer:

```
 Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
    If Timer4.Enabled = True Then
        Dim pingreq As Ping = New Ping()
        Dim rep As PingReply = pingreq.Send(NsTextBox1.Text)
        NsTextBox4.Text = NsTextBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine + ("Reply from " + NsTextBox1.Text + ":" + NsTextBox2.Text + "| time= " + rep.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms")
        If rep.RoundtripTime = 0 Then
            Timer4.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Button:

```
 Private Sub NsButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NsButton2.Click

    Timer4.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get rid of the timer and just await a task that performs your ping right from the button handler, like this:

```
Private Async Sub NsButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NsButton2.Click
    Dim t = Task(Of PingReply).Run(
        Function()
            Dim pingreq As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim rep As PingReply = pingreq.Send(NsTextBox1.Text)
            Return rep
        End Function)

    Dim result = Await t

    NsTextBox4.Text = NsTextBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine +
        ("Reply from " + NsTextBox1.Text + ":" + NsTextBox2.Text +
         "| time= " + result.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms")
End Sub
```

Comment: I never thought of it that way, but there seems to be an error within this code

Comment: `Dim result = Await t`Await can only be used as an async

Comment: I doubt the error is "Await can only be used as an async".  Can you copy and paste the *full* error message?  Also, did you put `Async` at the top of the `Sub`, i.e. `Private **Async** Sub`, like I have it?

Comment: rory.apI am trying to learn vb, and you taught me something new, thank you. That's what happened, I forgot to add it in the private sub. Thank you for the help appreciate it.

Comment: Nice little snippet, but why make your own asynchronous wrapper when there's the [**`SendAsync()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @VisualVincent -- Good point, that completely didn't occur to me.